# Django con UserCreationForm como usar los campos opcionales.-

Tags: python, django-models

estoy siguiendo un video-curso de Django y he llegado a la parte de registro de usuario, usando la clase UserCreationForm, en él se pone ejemplos con los campos que son obligatorios por defecto, username, password, pero no indica, y tampoco encuentro, como mostrar los que son opcionales, como el email, firstname, etc, solo me interesa el email. Desconozco si hay que crear un modelo nuevo con lo que necesito o hay alguna forma de usarlo.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import View
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm,AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login,logout
from django.contrib import messages

# Create your views here.

class VRegistro(View):

    def get(self,request):
        form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request, "registro/registro.html",{"form":form})

    def post(self,request):
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            usuario = form.save()
            login(request,usuario)
            return redirect('Home')
        else:
            for msg in form.error_messages:
                messages.error(request, form.error_messages[msg])
            return render(request, "registro/registro.html",{"form":form})

def cerrar_sesion (request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('Home')

def loguear (request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, "usuarios.html",{"form":form})
```

registro.html

```
{% extends "Otrawebapp/base.html" %}
    {% load static %}
    <!--{% load crispy_forms_tags %}-->
    {% block content %}
        <form method="post" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div style="width: 25%; margin:auto">
                <!-- {{form|crispy}} -->
                {{form}}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="background-color: #15317E;">Registro</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        {% endblock %}
```

form.py

```
from django import forms

class Registro(forms.Form):
    pass
```

Necesitaría mostrar el campo email, junto con el usuario y la password en el formulario de registro. Gracias anticipadas.

Comment: Yo tengo la misma duda que tu cómo lo soluccionaste

Comment: Para acceder a cada campo {{form.username}} (p.e.), como los definiste en el forms.py. Haciendo {% load crispy_forms_tags %} en el .html. Espero haberme explicado.